# antaŭ ol + infinitive?

Tags: word-usage

I am confused on whether I should use the infinitive form of the verb after `antaŭ ol`.

> Lavu viajn manojn antaŭ ol **forlasi** la banejon.
>
> *Wash your hands before leaving the bathroom.*

or

> Lavu viajn manojn antaŭ ol **vi forlasas** la banejon.
>
> *Wash your hands before you leave the bathroom.*

Are they both grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have two verbs in the same clause with a different tense, therefore the second verb should have no tense, like the infinitive or a gerund, or it should be the same tense as the first. Just like in English we would say "Wash (imperative) your hands before you leave (infinitive) the washroom."

It is better to say *eliri*, which means to exit. Also, because the person is coming out of the washroom, the accusative or a preposition should be used.

- Lavu viajn manojn antaŭ ol elir**i** la banejo**n**.
- Lavu viajn manojn antaŭ ol elir**i** **el** la banejo.

This is a general statement. The person may or may not be in the washroom.

---

If the time is specific then you need to divide it into 2 clauses with a comma and by adding the pronoun *vi*:

- Lavu viajn manojn, antaŭ ol vi elir**os** la banejo**n**.
- Lavu viajn manojn, antaŭ ol vi elir**os** **el** la banejo.

The person is currently in the washroom.

---

You can use any tense after *antaŭ ol*. From the tekstaro:

- ...ke ĉiu, antaŭ ol komenc**i** la legadon...
- Oni devas iri longan distancon, antaŭ ol ven**i** al la rivero...
- ...kien flugas la hirundoj, antaŭ ol ven**as** nia vintro...
- Ĉar antaŭ ol troviĝ**as** vorto sur mia lango...
- Ke, antaŭ ol ven**os** la vojaĝa kaleŝo...

Comment: Strictly speaking _leaving_ is not an infinitive (that would be _leave_), but a gerund (which -- like the infinitive -- has got no tense).

Comment: This answer seems a little confusing because the first part says that you can’t have two verbs with different tenses in one sentence but then in the second part it recommends to do exactly that.

Comment: You are right. I meant to say in the same clause, you can't have two different tenses. Edited.

Comment: "Lavu viajn manojn, antaŭ ol vi forlasos el la banejo." ne estas ĝusta laŭ mi, ĉar *forlasos* estas transitiva kaj bezonas objekton.

Comment: How would it be if one uses _after_ instead of _before_? For example: He left the bathroom after washing his hands.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the subject in the second part of the sentence you have a tense, without the subject it should be -i. The sentences listed above with -as -is -os are fine because there's a subject in that part of the sentence.
Mi helpos vin antaŭ ol fari tion.
I'll help you before doing that.
Mi helpos vin antaŭ ol mi faros tion.
I'll help you before I do that.
You can't say "antaŭ ol faros tion" without "mi."